# Spark: Reading data frame from list of paths with empty path

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to load dataframe from a list of paths in spark. If a file exists in all the mentioned paths then the code is working fine. If there is at least one path that is empty then it is throwing error.

This is my code:

```
val paths = List("path1", "path2")
val df = spark.read.json(paths: _*)
```

I looked at other options.

1. Build a single regex string which contains all the paths.
2. Building a list from the master list of paths by checking if spark can read or not.

.

```
for(path <- paths) {
  if(Try(spark.read.json(path)).isSuccess) {
    //add path to list
  }
}
```

The first approach won't work for my case because I can't create a regex out the paths I have to read.
Second approach works but I feel it is going to degrade performance as it has to read from all the paths twice.

Please suggest an approach to solve this issue.

Note:

1. All the paths are in hdfs
2. Each path is itself a regex string which will read from multiple files

Comment: Rather than read with json, you can just check if the directory is empty (with a simple native scala / java.io function) or not, can't you ?

Comment: I doubt performance is an issue here, but I have noted that an empty dir causes an issue

Comment: Not sure spark.read.json is the correct approach though

Comment: @tricky The paths I am taking as input are regex paths. I believe to check whether folder exists or not in hdfs, I need to provide absolute path. It would be complicated to break the regex and check for each directory whether it has content or not

Comment: I never thought of using spark.read.json in this way.

Comment: @thebluephantom yeah even I am doing for first time. necessity is mother of invention

Comment: The interface with that empty file is painful. You can always add an empty file to each dir which would neutralize the problem by and large.

Comment: Check overhead of try. I would add dummy file.

Comment: Why not `filter` the initial list of paths by checking which paths are empty using the FileSystem API and then pass the filtered list to JSON Reader?

Comment: @philantrovert each path will be a regex string like `path_prefix/folder1[2-8]/*`. Wouldn't I have to break regex and build paths and check in file system. I believe this might add more complexity or is there any better approach to break.

Comment: @philantrovert also, you can't assume that it's a filesystem path.  Is it S3?  HDFS?  Local file?  Something else?  You need spark apis.

Comment: @JamesMoore By FileSystem path, I meant the `FileSystem` under `org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem` which is what the OP was expecting

Comment: @philantrovert that doesn't read things like s3, though, does it?

Comment: @JamesMoore For S3, the equivalent is `org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3.S3FileSystem`

Comment: @philantrovert But you don't want to have to know in advance what your filesystem is - you don't need to know that when you call something like spark.read.text("somethingNew://moo/bark/*") for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use HDFS `FileSystem` API to get a list of paths that exist based on your regex (as long as it's a valid regex).

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

val path = Array("path_prefix/folder1[2-8]/*", "path_prefix/folder2[2-8]/*")

val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)  // sc = SparkContext

val paths = path.flatMap(p => fs.globStatus(new Path(p)).map(_.getPath.toString))
```

This way even if, say, `/path_prefix/folder13` is empty, it's contents will not get listed in the variable `paths` which will be a `Array[String]` containing all the available files in the regex.

Finally, you can do:

```scala
spark.read.json(paths : _*)
```

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you. I was under the assumption that I need to pass absolute paths to hdfs api to get the status of files

Comment: Would the same work for Blobstore too? val fs: FileSystem = FileSystem.get(sc.hadoopConfiguration)

Answer (score 1):

Add, copy dummy file with 0 length to the directories in path list is a pragmatic techical work around that functionally equates to what you want to do. The empty dir problem I have encountered before and alleviated this way, may be not possible for you...

Comment: I will try to implement this approach. If it solves I will let you know

Comment: Your comment on alternative was equally fine.